# How to sort data using datepicker in Angular 7?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an app where I'm fetching data from a database(postgres) and displaying it on the frontend in a tabular format. I have the datepicker from ngx-bootstrap and want to sort the dates according to the input from the displayed table. Achieving this is somewhat tricky since orderByPipes is already deprecated https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

A somewhat similar solution is https://auth0.com/blog/real-world-angular-series-part-3/#angular-filterSort-service but that again doesn't solve the problem when datepicker is in the question.

I have tried implementing the auth0 tutorial, but here it is mainly to sort the dates in a sorted manner and not based on datepicker input.

ngx-bootstrap code for datepicker

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue">
  </div>
</div>
```

Code for the component

Component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let rep of report">
  <tr>
    <th>{{rep.Date | date : fullTime}}</th>
    <th>{{rep["1"]}}</th>
    <th>{{rep["2"]}}</th>
    <th>{{rep["3"]}}</th>
    <th>{{rep["4"]}}</th>
    <th>{{rep["5"]}}</th>
    <th>{{rep["6"]}}</th>
    <th>{{rep["7"]}}</th>
    <th>{{rep["8"]}}</th>
  </tr>
</div>
```

The typescript code for datepicker is just to update to the current value but doesn't really help other than working as a placeholder

```
  bsValue = new Date();
```

What I want to achieve with the datepicker is that when I select a date from it, I want my app to display the data from that particular date in a sorted manner (descending/ascending). I don't want my backend data to change, only the frontend display should be sorted.

Comment: By which column you want to sort? Because you'll be having only single date. It would be helpful, if you can provide component ts and html code.

Comment: I want to sort by the date column but I want to sort all the data associated with it. Code for the markup component is added and ts code doesn't really have anything except the `bsValue` and a subscription to a service which is fetching the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen `(bsValueChange)="onValueChange($event)"` event of the datepicker and on each date change filter your data.